# How to send data from server side(node js) to client side(pug)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I am trying to use ajax to send data from client-side to server-side without refreshing the page.

I am using this ajax code inside my pug file -

```
script.
        $(function() {
            $('#form1').submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var form = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    type: form.attr('method'),
                    url: form.attr('action'),
                    data: {form.serialize()}
                });
            });
        });
```

I am using the same URL and the method(which is POST).

Router file:-

```
const express = require("express");

const main_controller = require("../../controllers/main-controller");

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/form', main_controller.Send);

module.exports = router;
```

Controller file:-

```
const data_model = require('../../models/data-model');

exports.Send = (req, res, next) => {
    data_model.find((err, data) => {
        res.render("./customer/form1", {
            pageTitle: "Form1",
            data: data
        });
    });
};
```

I want to filter the data I am sending above. In the form, I have dropdown boxes in which I'm displaying the data, when the user selects something, I am sending the option he chose to the server.
In the server, I am filtering data based on the option that was selected. I want to send the filtered data back to the client-side, but I am not able to.

Comment: Do you want to send the data back to the client _when_ the client sends an AJAX request, or do you need to send data to the client at any time?

Comment: @code I want to send data when I receive the data.

Comment: In jQuery AJAX, there's an attribute you can put in called `onSuccess` which should be a function which has a argument `res` where you can access the result sent from the server.

Comment: @code I don't think I fully understand what you mean there. So can you please give an example?

Comment: For example, on the client-side if you're sending a request to say, `/test-endpoint`, and in the server you handle the request and in the end of the callback do like `res.send("Some data for you!!")`, in the $.ajax object you are providing as a parameter, add `success: function(data) { console.log(data); /* right here! */ }`

Comment: @code When I am using `res.send()` It's displaying the thing in the `res.send()` instead of my page.

Comment: Yes, so now remove `res.send()` and render your page, and try displaying the result on the client-side.

Comment: @code It gives me an error saying `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: How many functions in `res` did you call? You can only call one.

Comment: @code I know, and that's my problem cause I need the same URL with the same method and so I have the same middleware and can't send more than 1 res.

Comment: Does your answer include the server-side code that sends a response to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery, you can use the `success` callback or the `.done` Promise Resolution for accessing data sent back by the server for further processing. Please have [a look here at the documentation][1] for further examples on how to do this.

[1]: [https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#:~:text=%24.post(%20%22test.php%22%2C%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22John%22%2C%20time%3A%20%222pm%22%20%7D),%7D](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#:%7E:text=%24.post(%20%22test.php%22%2C%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22John%22%2C%20time%3A%20%222pm%22%20%7D),%7D))%3B